# Receiving email takes upto 3 hours

Tags: cakephp-2.0

This is my code I am facing problem in receiving mail it take up to 3 hours. Please help me.

```
function sendMail($to, $subject, $template, $from,$params,$attachmentFile=array(),$layout='default') {

foreach($params as $key=>$val) {

$this->set("".$key."",$val);

}

$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';

if (is_array($to))

$this->Email->to = $to;

else

$this->Email->to = "<".$to.">";

//$this->Email->to;

$this->Email->subject = $subject;

$this->Email->layout = $layout;

$this->Email->replyTo = "test@gmail.com";

$this->Email->from = "test@gmail.com";

$this->Email->attachments = $attachmentFile;

$this->Email->template = $template; // note no '.ctp'

//echo "<pre>";print_r($this->Email);

//die();

if(!$this->Email->send()) {

return 0;

}

else {

return 1;

}

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to mark the code you included as code. You probably want to indent the code though to help with readability.

Comment: Also as it stands we can't actually diagnose the problem for you. Can you try sending to a mail server you can control and post the logs from that perhaps? It's probably getting greylisted by a spam filter somewhere along the line, but it's not possible to determine this from the information you have posted. Does this happen when you send to other domains too?

Answer (score 2):

Email is not instant. Sometimes a normal email will take quite a while. I would check what server (be it an SMTP server or plain old sendmail) you are using though and try to send mail through that normally to see how long it takes to make sure that it's not a cakephp configuration issue.